What is this special behavior with document.cookie? Setting document.cookie to a plain value (no key)
So far this behavior is in Chrome and Firefox (latest versions of each).
Let's say we set some cookies with the following JavaScript:
document.cookie = "is_halloween=true";
document.cookie = "skeletons=spooky";

Now let's break the rules and do this:
document.cookie = "BOO";

If we check the value of document.cookie in the console, it looks like this:
is_halloween=true; skeletons=spooky; BOO

What exactly is BOO? If we try to remove it with the following code, nothing happens:
document.cookie = "BOO=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT;";

document.cookie is still equal to is_halloween=true; skeletons=spooky; BOO
If we set document.cookie to an empty string:
document.cookie = "";

document.cookie is still equal to is_halloween=true; skeletons=spooky; BOO
Questions:
1. Is this special behavior in document.cookie intended to be used as a free text field for custom cookie syntax? If so, is it documented anywhere?
2. How do I get rid of BOO? The normal method of setting the expires field isn't working.

Edit: BOO can be removed with document.cookie="Boo;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"

Have you tried document.cookie="Boo;expires=0"?

Also the document.cookie API is from the Bronze Age. It is weird, but it will probably never significantly change (except for backwards-friendly enhancements every once in a while).

you'd actually use expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" (or any past date) not expires=0

@JaromandaX MDN says otherwise? (I haven't tried it in years because my personal opinion is that cookies should be managed at the server.)

@Pointy your suggestion of document.cookie="Boo;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT" actually worked

lol well it's not working in Firefox for me, even though MDN told me it would. But yaay.

Also just from basic instinct, I'm not 100% sure I trust what document.cookie says to be the exact set of cookies that are sent with an outgoing HTTP request. I mean, maybe it is, but I would not be inclined to trust it without testing because, well I just wouldn't.

@Pointy correction--you have to use the full date string for it to work: document.cookie="Boo;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"

Yea not surprised, I just saw something on MDN, but of course it's just a wiki.

@Pointy - I tried, setting it to "0" makes it a session cookie rather than deleting it

I would definitely not have guessed that, but OK

cookies are mysterious at times :p
